# Using Macbook pro ethernet as a DHCP server

Tags: mac, ethernet, dhcp

I'm developing an arduino project with an Ethernet shield.
In order to simulate that the arduino is connected to a router i simply want to make the Macbook act as a DHCP server and give the IP to the arduino board

how do i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use Internet Sharing from Sharing Preference Pane.

1. Open `System Preferences`
2. Select `Sharing` Preference Pane
3. Enable `Internet Sharing` with the following settings:

   `Share your connection from:` **`Wi-Fi`**

   `To computers using:` **`Ethernet`**

[Aleph 0](http://www.aleph0.com/computing/macosx/dhcp-setup/) has a more detailed article about it.

There's also an article by Jacques Fortier on [Running Mac OS X's built-in DHCP server](http://www.jacquesf.com/2011/04/mac-os-x-dhcp-server/)  that describes how you can do it manually.

Comment: i love you, it was just so straightforward

Comment: As of August 2017, Jacques Fortier's site was having problems (at least, for me it was), but I found this: https://www.swissns.ch/site/2014/05/running-mac-os-xs-built-in-dhcp-server/